# How to Map JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have JSON format , but how to map the given JSON in Recat. Can anybody suggest me the solution?For Simple JSON I know how to Map, but here how can I map?

Here is the JSON:

```
const JSON = [
  {
    column1: {
      display_name: "Status",
      content: "<>",
      isMandatory: true / false,
      order: 1,
      enable: true / false,
    },
    column2: {
      display_name: "Study",
      content: "<>",
      isMandatory: true / false,
      order: 2,
      enable: true / false,
    },
    column3: {
      display_name: "Status",
      content: "<>",
      isMandatory: true / false,
      order: 1,
      enable: true / false,
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “map”

Comment: {JSON.map((study, index) => (<div>study.display_name</div>))} I want map something like this for each column1 ,column2...etc, But how can I do for above Json

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON[0]).map(item => {})`. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: A few things that might seem pedantic but are relevant: (1) This is unrelated to React, (2) JSON is a string -- this is an object, (3) `true/false` is not valid syntax, (4) please show your desired output after mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @AbinThaha, Thank you, This is what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to map the data like

`Object.keys(JSON[0]).map(item => {})`.

This will help

In order to access the item inside, you can do as

`Object.keys(JSON[0]).map(item => JSON[0][item])`

Comment: Hi, here in item I'm getting just String Column1 instead of object of Column1. How to get that?

Comment: Have updated the answer to handle the situation

Comment: Hi, I'm using like this   {Object.keys(JSON[0]).map((item, index) => (
                <Panel
                  index
                  header={JSON[0][item].display_name}
                  key={index}
                >
    </Panel>
    ))}

Comment: react-dom.development.js:13413 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {display_name, content, isMandatory, order, enable}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can you please  tell me how can I use it?

Comment: Yeah, I am checking in my a mockup, gimme a minute